# How should I flag a question that includes the answer?

Tags: support

How should I flag a question by someone who hasn't understood the Q&A format of this site and posts an answer in his own question (like a guide)? Should I flag it for moderator attention? The other flag reasons seem not to fit, or did I overlook a fitting one?

For example: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203663/what-is-a-good-way-to-farm-canfies-in-candy-box-2

[image]

Comment: Easy: Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a new user that doesn't understand how our site works. It happens. They try and share their knowledge with the community (a good thing!), but are unsure exactly how to go about it.

It *general* cases, I wouldn't flag/vote to close straight away, but comment, and politely ask them to move the answer to the answer section. If, after a day or so with no response, I would post their answer as a Community Wiki answer, and edit it out of the question. *Good content is still good content*, and I would rather it be in a question/answer pair then closed and removed outright.

In this **specific** case however, the question itself seems *too subjective* to fit our site as it is currently written. A 'good' method to farm candies? According to what criteria? Amount of candies? Time/effort taken to farm? For this specific case, I would flag as **Too Broad**.

Comment: This seems to be more sensible to me. He had good intentions, now the whole answer part has just been edited out and it will probably just be deleted.

Comment: @Kodama the answer still exists in the revision history, so it can be retrieved if necessary, but while I disagree with the close reason I do think *this* question should still be closed, for the reason stated above.

Answer (score 0):

As Frank said, is unclear what the OP is asking, because he (seemly) already solved his problem, therefore *we* have no idea what the question is, what is trying to be solved, what is the goal.